# Two genvar in single genarte for loop?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is below sort of generate loop is valid in system verilog.

```
genvar i,j;

for (i=0,j=5; i<5 && j<10; i++,j++) begin:M1

    integer t;

    initial begin

    t = i*j;

end

endgenerate
```

Comment: No, It dosn't work for me. error in compilation it self.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I'm not even sure what the behavior of this code should be, or in what order they execute.

```
genvar i,j;
for (i = 0; i <5; i++) begin
    for (j = 5; j < 10; j++) begin
        $display("%d", i*j);
    end
end
```

you don't need 'endgenerate' in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do much with genvars in your example.

The following code mimics what you asked for, but it might not work with all simulators. It works with synopsys vcs but does not work with icarus.

```
module g;
   genvar i;
   for (i=0; i<5; i++) begin:M
      if (i == 0) begin:B
         parameter j = 5;
      end
      else begin:B
         parameter j = g.M[i-1].B.j + 1;
      end

      integer t;
      initial begin
         t = i*B.j;
         $display(i, B.j, t);
      end
   end // block: M
endmodule // g
```

the idea is to declare the parameter `j` inside the generate loop so that its value is an increment of the value declared in the previous iteration. You need to add a named block 'B' to declare conditionally.